# How to test significance between rates of occurrences

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

Without going into domain specific information, I have a data set in which I'm testing the rate of occurrences of an event like so:

Event 1

# of trials: 378

# of occurrences: 109

# of occurrences in case 1: 12

# of occurrences in case 2: 45

# of occurrences in case 3: 51

I want to find out if there is a significant difference in the occurrence of the event between those three test cases.  I expect that case 1 will be significantly different, while case 2 and 3 will show no significant difference in their occurrence.

I think I need a chi square, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set it up because I only have one dimension.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a hypothesis test for proportions. To the extent of my knowledge, you'll want to test the difference between the proportions of each variable (i.e - H0: C1 = C2, H0: C1 = C3, H0: C2 = C3) but there may be some kind of method to test all three at once that someone else can suggest.